# Adding triples to Surf RDF in Python with a context/graph

Tags: python, sesame, rdflib

In python, I'm trying to add triples to a Sesame data store using Surf RDF.

However, using the following:

```
session.default_store.add_triple (s, p, o, surf.rdf.URIRef("http://hi/me"))
```

causes the triples are added, but without the context. So s, p, o are added to the store but not to any context.

Am I doing something wrong with the context? Has anyone else had this issue?

Alternately, what's a good way of putting all these in?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can also work with Sesame and Python with RDFAlchemy which has a rather good sesame support.

The code is now maintained and alive here :
https://github.com/gjhiggins/RDFAlchemy

Comment: Thanks for that. I was hoping I could solve it in Surf as I've done quite a bit of work in it, but I'll rewrite in RDFAlchemy and see how I go.